# After a non null return from a SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() call, do I need to check for empty string after casting to string?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, exception

```
object check;
string q = "query details";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sc))
{
    try
    {
        sc.Open();
        check = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        sc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Alert user, continue execution;
        CloseConnectionIfOpen(sc);
        return s;
    }

    if (check == null)
    {
        // Alert user, continue execution;
        return s;
    } 
    else
    {
        stringvariable = check.ToString();
    }
}
```

Do I now need to check if `stringvariable` is an empty string, or can I guarantee it has at least 1 character?

If I can guarantee that the string is not empty, then would it make more sense to just go ahead and attempt to cast the return from `ExecuteScalar()` and catch the exception?

Comment: An empty string != null string, so you really should check that it has something in it. You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check if it is one or the other.

Comment: I think that would work except that to get that far I would have to attempt to cast the null object as a string and the exception would be thrown before getting to a point that I could call IsNullOrEmpty(). Your first sentence confirmed what I thought.

Comment: Working on a deadline using a legacy database filled with information I can't touch. I would really rather not take my company's time to start up a new console program, create a dummy database, input a row with an empty string then run the program for a quick question. I can do the safe thing for now and check the object and then the string, which is what I'm doing while I wait to see if anyone has any input.

Comment: You've **only** established that the return value from `ExecuteScalar()` is **NOT NULL** - nothing more. ***YES*** - if it's a string, it **can be** an empty string - that's also *not null*

Answer (score 0):

From :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.80).aspx

> Return Value
>   The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference if the result set is empty.

So, no need to check for an empty string in stringvariable.

On your second question. You should not expect an exception. Exception is something that is unexpected. If you known that you SQL query could fail, then you should be proactive and explicitly test if check != null.